# Referencing a specific column in foreign row

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
TableA:
ID     NAME

0      Thomas
1      Johnson
2      Harry

TableB:

ID     IDA     ANAME
0      2       Harry
1      0       Thomas
2      1       Johnson
```

I've created a foreign key in "TableB" on column "IDA" which referenced "ID" in "TableA", with the following:

```
FOREIGN KEY (IDA) REFERENCES TableA(ID)
```

For a given row in "TableB", I'm able to get the corresponding row in "TableA" as defined by the above constraint. How then do I make sure that the "ANAME" of a particular row in "TableB" takes on the value of "NAME" in this corresponding row in "TableA"? I've tried the following, but unfortunately it turns out to be invalid (Missing Logic near "ANAME" error)

```
FOREIGN KEY (IDA) REFERENCES TableA(ID) ON UPDATE SET ANAME = TableA.Name
```

Answer (score 3):

Short answer - duplicating data across tables is almost never a good idea, so just don't do that.

Use your foreign key on the ID column to fetch your names from TableA whenever you need them, so instead of

```
  SELECT id, ida, aname 
  FROM TableB;
```

use

```
  SELECT b.id, b.ida, a.name AS aname
  FROM TableB b
  JOIN TableA ON b.ida = a.id;
```